# phonegap 2.2 orientation change does not resize app

Tags: ios, cordova

I didn't have this problem on previous versions of Phonegap. But in 2.2, when I change the orientation, it doesn't update the `uiwebview`.

Does phonegap not support landscape view by default? How do you handle this?

[image: problem]

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is not an issue with the WebView getting updated but with the meta tag in the index.html's document head.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

After removing the unnecessary `height=device-height` everything works just fine

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

[image: landscape is supported]

Comment: Thank you so much, height=device-height was working (wasn't hurting) on Android, after deleting it for iOs I re-tested with android and saw it was unnecessary in the first place, so a great solution

Comment: Yes but if you remove height=device-height you get problems with the keyboard covering the screen.

Answer (score 4):

To add to Stephan's answer, if you need to do anything special when the orientation changes, you can set a callback function to:

window.onorientationchange

Answer (score 3):

## I have also have same issue in ios phonegap ....

Just go and update x-code project file (IOS Application target ) change or update support interface orientation and check it all orientation .

it's work well ...

Comment: Yep this was it. in Xcode Targets-> Your App -> iPhone/iPad Deployment Info -> "Supported Interface Orientations". Click each orientation you wish to support. By default it seems only Portrait is enabled.

Comment: code-wise these options sit in `platforms/ios/appname/appname-Info.plist`, `<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceConstant</string>
    </array>` replace string `UIInterfaceConstant` with any of [these constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIInterfaceOrientation) (so one string element per supported orientation). For iPad it's the same thing but the key is `<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.addEventListener(
    "orientationchange",
    function() {
        // Announce the new orientation number
        location.reload();
    }, false );
```