# Jquery resize event doesn't work in Phonegap IOS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

The 'resize' event detect right on android but in the IOS it doesn't detect it

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
   //code
});
```

Comment: Please check if it helps.
Hope it helps in some manner.

[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649086/detect-rotation-of-android-phone-in-the-browser-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you viewport is set correctly. You should not have it bound to `device-height`. see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13551413/390330